# Combinations without repetition (python)

Tags: python, string

I want to make the following combinations:

```
string.1 string.1
string.2 string.2 string.1
string.3 string.3 string.2 string.1
string.4 string.4 string.3 string.2
string.4 string.1
```

Each item should be combined with every other one, but the order does not matter, i.e. `string.4 string.1` is the same as `string.1 string.4`. Also, there should be a maximum of 4 combinations per line. Each item in the first column is combined with each one in the other columns. For example in line 2, there are the combinations `string.2-string.2` & `string.2-string.1`.

This is my code:

```
import itertools
BLOCKS=4
DB="string"
getiter = lambda : itertools.chain( range(1, BLOCKS+1))
for i in getiter():
    for j in range(1, BLOCKS, 4):
            emit = f"{DB}.{i}"
            for k in range(4):
                    if j + k > BLOCKS:
                            break
                    emit += " {}.{}".format(DB, j+k)
            print(emit)
```

And this is my current output:

```
string.1 string.1 string.2 string.3 string.4
string.2 string.1 string.2 string.3 string.4
string.3 string.1 string.2 string.3 string.4
string.4 string.1 string.2 string.3 string.4
```

Here, there are combinations that are superfluous. How do I get rid of those?

Comment: I don't understand the rules for the combinations. You have `string.4 string.1`, but not `string.4 string.2`, nor `string.4 string.3`.

Comment: Sorry, I added the explanation. The item in the first column stays "fixed", and is combined with each item in the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that :

```
import itertools
BLOCKS=4
DB="string"
getiter = lambda : itertools.chain( range(1, BLOCKS+1))
for i in getiter():
    emit = f"{DB}.{i}"
    for k in range(1, BLOCKS+1):
        if k > BLOCKS: break
        else if k == i: continue #<========== Added
        emit += " {}.{}".format(DB, k)
    print(emit)
```

(Note that the second loop (j) seems useless so I did remove it)

Output :

```
string.1 string.2 string.3 string.4
string.2 string.1 string.3 string.4
string.3 string.1 string.2 string.4
string.4 string.1 string.2 string.3
```

Comment: Thank you, but here there are repetitions. The column is fixed, and the item combined with every other item in the same line. So the first line combines 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, the second line 2-1, 2-3, 4-2. The combination 1-2 is the same as 2-1 as the order does not matter.